# Is it possible to find window.innerheight when the browser is in fullscreen or MAXIMIZED?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently making a game in javascript, and because of a scaling issue, I need to find the maximum window.innerheight and window.innerwidth like when the browser is maximized. When I open a browser that is not maximized, and just use window.innerheight and width, it becomes a problem.

Is this possible and is there any way calculation to find the maximum innerheight and innerwidth on full screen.

Comment: Why is that necessary?

Comment: Listen for `resize` on `window` and recalculate from there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also listen to "onfullscreenchange" (https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/onfullscreenchange)

Comment: like i meant is there a way to find max inner width before the fullscreen changes? do you mean request the full screen?